# EACH event binding on dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery

i have this func :

```
$(".card").each(function() {
  $(this)
    .closest('.collapse-group')
    .find('.btn')
    .toggle($(this).text().length > 16);
});
```

But I need to transform it when the elements are dynamically appended, for example i know how it to do for `click` func, but on `EACH` - no:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var $this = $(this);
          var $collapse = $this.closest('.collapse-group').find('.collapse');
          $collapse.collapse('toggle');
        }); //- this func works

 $(document).on('each', ".card", function() {
      $(this)
        .closest('.collapse-group')
        .find('.btn')
        .toggle($(this).text().length > 16);
    });//??? - this func does not work
```

insert it right under the block where I append the cards does not work:

```
var card =
              `<hr>
            <h3>
          <p class="text-center " >${title}</p>
          </h3>
            <img class="col-12 ml-auto col-12 mr-auto" src=${images}>
            <div class="span4 collapse-group">
              <div class="text-center">
                <p><a class="btn btn-md btn-outline-dark btn-square" href="#">Check &raquo;</a></p>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse">
                <div class="card card-body">
                ${text}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>`
            $('.container').append(card)
            $(document).find(".card").each(function() {
              $(this)
                .closest('.collapse-group')
                .find('.btn')
                .toggle($(this).text().length > 16);
            });
```

Comment: Put the `each()` logic in a function and then call that function right after you append the new elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` is not an event so cannot use with `.on`. Try below function to iterate cards

```
 $('.container').find(".card").each(function() {
       var toggle = $(this).text().length > 16;
       var collapseGroup = $(this).closest('.collapse-group');
       collapseGroup.find('.btn').toggle(toggle);
    });
```

Comment: where are you appending the dynamic elements? you need to call above code right after it. can you try that

Comment: updated the body of the question, immediately below the appended block

Comment: please put `;` after `$('.container').append(card)`. I have updated my post, can you please try with it now

Comment: unfortunately the problem still exist

Comment: can you recreate it on jsfiddle or code snipped? also look for browser console error if any

Comment: very strange, when i when I removed from the function `.length > 16`, and left only `var toggle = $(this).text()`  my buttons started to fade and appear, earlier when there were condition `.length > 16` it works, `.length > 16` meant that  `<div class="card card-body">` empty or not.   if I got the empty text the length of `<div class="card card-body">`, was still 16, why so I do not know

Comment: Now the length of empty block is 34 , not 16 :-))

Comment: oh ok .. thats great .. so you got your code working :)